# How to set a tab as not-clickable

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three tabs in a tabhost.
I can switch between the three tabs.
However I want the third tab to be not clickable. That will be triggered by a diff button in tab one.

Any help as how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

If you want to disable one tab button on TabWidget, then try this code:

// tabHost = ... (get TabHost)

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(your_index).setEnabled(false);
```

If you want to disable tab widget in overall, then:

// tabWidget = ... (get TabWidget)

```
 tabWidget.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Any idea how we can achieve this if one has created tabs using FragmentActivity and not used TabHost?